# New-ADUser processing an object, getting error "The parameter is incorrect"

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am utilizing a script to read information from a word document and place it into a csv. When I open up the csv the information is contained within double quotes.

Here is the CSV file:

```
fname,lname,jobtitle,department,manager,pagernumber
"Test","Taco","MedAssist","TestingDepot","BOSSMAN","9999"
"Test","T","TestingDummy","4220","Bossman","9990"
```

The `New-AdUser` code I am using is incorrect so I am posting the code for viewing.

```
#_________________________________EXCEL TIME_________________________________


#Store the data from ADUsers.csv in the $ADUsers variable
$ADUsers = Import-csv C:\Users\username\Desktop\newusers.csv

#Loop through each row containing user details in the CSV file 
foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{
    #Read user data from each field in each row and assign the data to a variable as below
    $fname = $User.fname
    $fname = $fname | Out-String
    $lname = $User.lname
    $lname = $lname | Out-String
    $fn1 = $fname.Substring(0,1)
    $username = "$fn1$lname"
    $jobtitle = $User.jobtitle
    $jobtitle = $jobtitle | Out-String 
    $department = $User.department
    $department = $department | Out-String
    $manager = $User.manager
    $manager = $manager | Out-String
    $pagernumber = $User.pagernumber
    $pagernumber = $pagernumber | Out-String
    Write-Output $fname
    Write-Output $lname
    
    #Check to see if the user already exists in AD
    if (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $username})
    {
         #If user does exist, give a warning
         Write-Warning "A user account with username $username already exists in Active Directory."
           pause
    }
    else
    {
        #User does not exist then proceed to create the new user account 
      
        $userProps = [PSCustomObject]@{
        SamAccountName  = $username
        Name            = "$fname $lname"
        GivenName       = $fname
        Surname         = $lname
        Enabled         = $True
        DisplayName     = "$lname $fname"
        Company         = "Companyname"
        AccountPassword = (ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -Force)
        HomeDrive       = "X:"
        ScriptPath      = "K32.exe"
        OtherAttributes = @{pager=$pagernumber}
        Title           = $jobtitle
        Department      = $department
        Description     = $jobtitle
        # Manager       = $manager
        # HomeDirectory = $folder
                      }

        New-ADUser @userProps
        #Profile - (Home Folder) Local Path should have U:\ As well as fix the remote tab to also have U:\
```

After running this code the error I get is:

> New-ADUser : The parameter is incorrect

How do I pass the object to `New-ADUser` properly?

Comment: In Windows PowerShell you _invariably_ get double-quoted fields (in PowerShell (Core) 7+ you can now control the behavior via [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv)'s `-QuoteFields` parameter). However, the double-quoting should _not_ be a problem. If you get blanks on calling `Import-Csv`, the problem must be a different one.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Now the issue i am getting lies in passing an object to New-AdUSer. Would you be able to help me find the correct way to pass a PSCustomOBject to New-ADUser?

Comment: Remove  `[PSCustomObject]` from your code: only _hashtables_ (and arrays, for positional arguments) can be used with [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting)

Comment: The removal of ```[PSCustomObject]``` Gives me the error "New-ADUser The Paramater is incorrect". Thank you for your help, I am new to PowerShell and this is teaching me a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear it; I don't have access to `New-ADUser`, so I can't help you further, but I suggest you clean up your question to focus on the remaining problem. I've also added the `active-directory` tag to the question, which will hopefully get the attention of subject-matter experts.

Comment: Does the error show which parameter is incorrect? Are there any empty values in your CSV perhaps? Does any of the SamAccountNames exceed the 20 character limit? Is manager `Bossman` any of these `A distinguished name, A GUID (objectGUID), A security identifier (objectSid) or A SAM account name sAMAccountName)` ?

Comment: The error does not show which parameter is incorrect. There are sometimes empty values but not often, is powershell unable to handle that? Bossman is not inside of Active Directory but I have been testing the code with this instance of code either edited out or with a proper Distinguished User. I did not know that there was a 20 char limit thank you for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read over your code and it looks like you are doing a few extra unnecessary things.

Why are you using  `| out-string`?

Remove that so your code looks like this

```
foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{
    #Read user data from each field in each row and assign the data to a variable as below
    $fname = $User.fname
    $lname = $User.lname
    $fn1 = $fname.Substring(0,1)
    $username = "$fn1$lname"
    $jobtitle = $User.jobtitle
    $department = $User.department
    $manager = $User.manager
    $pagernumber = $User.pagernumber
    Write-Output $fname
    Write-Output $lname
    
    #Check to see if the user already exists in AD
    if (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $username})
    {
         #If user does exist, give a warning
         Write-Warning "A user account with username $username already exists in Active Directory."
           pause
    }
    else
    {
        #User does not exist then proceed to create the new user account 
      
        $userProps = @{
        SamAccountName  = $username
        Name            = "$fname $lname"
        GivenName       = $fname
        Surname         = $lname
        Enabled         = $True
        DisplayName     = $lname + $fname
        Company         = "Companyname"
        AccountPassword = (ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -Force)
        HomeDrive       = "X:"
        ScriptPath      = "K32.exe"
        OtherAttributes = @{pager=$pagernumber}
        Title           = $jobtitle
        Department      = $department
        Description     = $jobtitle
        # Manager       = $manager
        # HomeDirectory = $folder
        }

        New-ADUser @userProps -Verbose
    }
}
```

Also, if you want to see what your hash table looks like as an object, use this code

```
[array]$obj = New-Object psobject -Property $userProps
```

Comment: The array obj helped me out a lot! Thank You! I was able to see inside the object and realized that the script was having trouble dealing with otherattributes as well as assigning a Samaccountname. I am not certain why this was happening but I just stopped using it as an object and it worked. Thank you for your help!